# Could I use if (snapShot.hasChild(uid) in firebaseRecycleOptions? I am using Firebase Recycle adapter to retrieve data under node: "Groups"

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
private void RetrieveAndDisplayGroups() {
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<GroupModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<GroupModel>()
            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups"), new SnapshotParser<GroupModel>() {
                @NonNull
                public GroupModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    // I tried to use if statment before return.
                    return new GroupModel(snapshot.child("groupName").getValue().toString(), snapshot.child("groupDescription").getValue().toString());
                }
            }).build();
    modelAdapter = new GroupModelAdapter(options, getContext());
    recyclerExploreGroupView.setAdapter(modelAdapter);
}
```

So I am making a group chat app.
In my app, I want to show the users only the groups they have created.
In the database, under node "Groups", I have all the groups created by all users.

I am using firebase recycle adapter to retrieve data from firebase real time database.
I am not familiar with how FirebaseRecycleOptions work. I think it returns a set of the model object I passed.

I try to use if statement before new firebaseRecycleOptions return. But I got red line.
The goal is to check if each group has a child as a requirement. And only retrieve the ones who have it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The return type is `GroupModel` meaning need to return a `GroupModel` but when you use an `if` statement then it causes error since the value is conditional. You can create an `EmptyGroupModel` to be returned if the condition isn't met.

Comment: "But I got red line." doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly is causing the code to provide that "red line"?

Comment: @DarShan Your suggestion works almost. But it creates empty card views of that empty group model any way. I want to return nothing for the groups that doesn't match my condition. If any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only show a subset of the child nodes in the adapter, you should use a query to retrieve only those child nodes from the database.

It's hard to be certain without seeing your database, but using this query in the adapter might be an option:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Groups")
    .orderByChild("groupName")
    .startAt(null)
```

Since `null` is the first value in [Firebase Realtime Database ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#data-order), this will return any node that has a `groupName` value.

Comment: Add your query in the adapter? where in the adapter? My adapter extends FirebaseRecycleAdapter. I don't know where to put the query in my GroupModelAdapter.java.

Comment: I have temporarily solved the problem by creating another node with the id of current user, inside which I store the groups he had created, in addition to storing all the groups all users have created under node, "Groups".

Comment: #1: replace the reference in here ` .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups"), ...`  with the query I showed.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. The problem was I was assigning the query you wrote to a database reference. Now I directly pass it inside setQuery method and it is working now. Though I don't need startAt(null).